# How to wrap ASP.net validation controls in Bootstrap classes?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap 3 with ASP.NET webforms and I am completely new to Bootstrap. The webform I am working on uses ASP.net validation controls. My web form has a standard layout with two columns and I am using "form-group" class to group my labels and input fields.

Now the problem is that as I am placing the label, input field as well as its validator in the Bootstrap "form-group" class, the message in the text property of the validator is being displayed in the next line after validation. I want that to be displayed right next to the input field. Is there any alternative way I can do this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtBox">Address <span class="required">*</span></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox id="txtBox" runat="server"  CssClass="form-control"/>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLine1" ValidationGroup="<%# ValidationGroup %>" ControlToValidate="txtBox" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Line 1 is required." Text="*"/>   
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the above code, Label and TextBox are stacked. How do you display in two columns (inline)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create validation in separate column.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .required {
            color: #e31937;
            font-family: Verdana;
            margin: 0 5px;
        }

        .field-validation-error {
            color: #e31937;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <div class="container form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label runat="server"
                    AssociatedControlID="txtBox"
                    CssClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 control-label">
                    Address 
                    <span class="required">*</span>
                </asp:Label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 ">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"
                        CssClass="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-control-static">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLine1"
                        ControlToValidate="txtBox" runat="server"
                        Display="Dynamic"
                        CssClass="field-validation-error"
                        Text="Line 1 is required." />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 ">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton"
                        Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah! I was trying to make it. Vote up.

Comment: Thanks Win! Its working. Although I did not use the same code, I incorporated your idea to perform validation in separate column and it worked. By the way the snippet I mentioned was just one set of form controls placed in one of the columns. I have divided the entire page  into two columns each containing multiple set of form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following: **Updated**

```
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Info</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Garage Name" CssClass="form-control username" ID="txtAddress"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-5">
            <span class="help-inline pull-left">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtAddress"
                    ErrorMessage="Address is a required field."
                    ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope, this is what you expected:

[image: Sample Image]

By the way, you didn't put the end tag in the RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: OP explicitly said Boostrap. OP wants to use Bootstrap's ***form-control*** class in TextBox.

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

#jQuery for check "require" validation for only submit button#

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function () {'use strict';
   window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
     if (form.checkValidity() === false) 
       {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
       }
     form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
        }, false);
      })();
```

##Submit button HTML##

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"   OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

##Non Submit button##

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch"  runat="server"    class="form-control btn-primary " Width="25%" Text="Find" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```